# Reading a list of tuples from a text file with strings and numbers

Tags: python, string, int, tuples

I have a text file where each line represents the results from a sequence mining operation. So the first element in each tuple is a tuple of strings (letters), and the second element is the frequency (int).

How can I read these back from the text file into the original format? Format as follows, copied directly from the text file.... Can't seem to find any similar examples out there but there's got to be a way to do this easily.

```
(('a',), 30838057)
(('a', 'b'), 23151399)
(('a', 'b', 'c'), 13865674)
(('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'), 8979035)
(('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'), 6771982)
(('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'), 4514076)
(('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), 2403374)
```

Comment: Those are valid Python literals, you can read each line with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). But it might be better to store them in a more standard format.

Comment: Not sure if it's the best way of doing this, but you could try doing a `replace()` to swap the round for square brackets and then run each line through the json module.
Edit: Interesting, I'd never come across the `literal_eval()` method (plain `eval()` obviously not being a good idea). I'd say it's a more elegant solution than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have commented you can use the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function since your data appears to be formatted the same a Python literals:

```
import ast
from pprint import pprint


filename = 'tuples_list.txt'

tuple_list = []
with open(filename) as inp:
    for line in inp:
        values = ast.literal_eval(line)
        tuple_list.append(values)

pprint(tuple_list)
```

Output:

```
[(('a',), 30838057),
 (('a', 'b'), 23151399),
 (('a', 'b', 'c'), 13865674),
 (('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'), 8979035),
 (('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'), 6771982),
 (('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'), 4514076),
 (('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), 2403374)]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just instead of printing, I append each line to a list and now I've got the data structure I want.

Comment: @Kingle: You're welcome. Note: Modified my answer slightly to show doing that.